# Vertical align the content of absolutely positioned td in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a absolutely positioned td (second td), I want it to align at vertical center even there is content changes in the first td.

I tried using position: relative and transform: properties and all, but nothing seems to worked out.

This is my code, and you can see the record payment buttons are not vertically centered.

```css
table {
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left:0%;
    border-style: solid;border-color:#eee;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:table;
}

table, th, td {
    border-width: thin;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;border-color:#eee;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
td {
    text-align: left;     

}

.hover-icons{
  position: absolute;
  right:30px;
}
.hover-icons ul{
  position: absolute;
   border: 0;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0;
   transform: translate(5%, 33%);
   background: #EFEFEF;
   height: auto;
   display: none;
}
td{padding:0px 0}
.hover-icons ul{
  display: flex;
}
.hover-icons ul li{
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.hover-main-icons .posi-r{position: relative;}
.btn-hover-i{

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<table class="hover-main-icons">
<tr>
<td>test test<br> test<br> test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttest<br>testt<br>est<br>test</td>
<td class="hover-icons">
                <div class="posi-r">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
<td>test test test test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttesttestt<br>est<br>test</td>
<td class="hover-icons">
                <div class="posi-r">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Is there any way to place buttons that are vertically centered?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
.hover-icons{
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
}
```

to

```
.hover-icons{
 position: relative;
 right:25%;
}
```

**Here is the working snippet:**

```css
table {
    width: 600px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left:0%;
    border-style: solid;border-color:#eee;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:table;
}

table, th, td {
    border-width: thin;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-style: solid;border-color:#eee;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
td {
    text-align: left;     

}

.hover-icons{
  position: relative;
  right:25%;
}
.hover-icons ul{
  position: absolute;
   border: 0;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0;
   transform: translate(5%, 33%);
   background: #EFEFEF;
   height: auto;
   display: none;
}
td{padding:0px 0}
.hover-icons ul{
  display: flex;
}
.hover-icons ul li{
  margin: 0 6px;
}
.hover-main-icons .posi-r{position: relative;}
.btn-hover-i{

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<table class="hover-main-icons">
<tr>
<td>test test<br> test<br> test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttest<br>testt<br>est<br>test</td>
<td class="hover-icons">
                <div class="posi-r">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
<td>test test test test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttesttestt<br>est<br>test</td>
<td class="hover-icons">
                <div class="posi-r">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: It is vertically centered. Maybe you mean horizontally centered? Because yes, it's not horizontally centered.

Comment: Top and bottom equal spacing for td inside each tr, that is what i mean vertically centered

Comment: So, you want it to be horizontally and vertically centered. Your question is wrong then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a "height" and "display:block;" to the tr o td and than the "line-height" for the vertical align. For example If the height is "height:300;" the line-height must be "line-height:300px;"

Ps. I think position:relative is the right choise

Answer (score 1):

Try this: without position css

```css
table {
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 0%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: table;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-width: thin;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-icons ul {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  height: auto;
  display: none;
}

td {
  padding: 0px 0
}

.hover-icons ul {
  display: flex;
}

.hover-icons ul li {
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.hover-main-icons .posi-r {
  position: relative;
}

.btn-hover-i {}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<table class="hover-main-icons">
  <tr>
    <td>test test<br> test<br> test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttest<br>testt<br>est<br>test</td>
    <td class="hover-icons">
      <div class="posi-r">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>test test test test<br>test<br> testtesttest testt<br>esttesttestt<br>est<br>test</td>
    <td class="hover-icons">
      <div class="posi-r">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href=""><button class="btn btn-red-bg btn-hover-i">Record Payment</button></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i need the position to display the buttons on the edge of the right corner in which table layout is scrollable, but the icons will stay at right always on hover...anyways thanks for the help..+1 :)